# What is 'core' in the command: rm -f *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm learning to Makefile! I included the whole **rm** command in case some arguments depend on one another:

```
rm -f \*~ core $(INCDIR)/\*~
```

I assume C++ generates some files that end in '~', so we delete those, but what is *core*? The only thing Google returns are tutorials that seem to assume its function is known already, but I can't find anything just saying "'core' is..."

**Rider:** Say '_OBJ' is a list of object files and 'ODIR' is a directory. Then...

```
$(patsubst %, $(ODIR)/%, $(_OBJ))
```

... takes any filename, *fname*, in '_OBJ' and replaces it with '$(ODIR)/fname'—thus moving it to the directory '$(ODIR)' with the name *fname*, correct?

Comment: Often, when a program aborts it generates a core dump in a file called 'core'.

Comment: Maybe I'm getting worse at the internet, or delving into more obscure things—but it seems like it's getting more and more difficult to find a simple, succinct tutorials. I've just read through [this](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/), and it's **awesome**.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Ah! That is simple enough. Thanks!

Comment: core is some file, supposedly generated during the built process. Files ending with `~` are usually editor generated backups, so removing them from inside a makefile is an **extremely** bad idea.

Comment: *"I assume C++ generates some files that end in '~'"* - Actually that happens with some text editors, they create backup files with `~` on the end

Comment: Said editors can and should be configured to put their `~` files elsewhere though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some (all?) Posix systems have a feature called *core dumps*. (It's disabled in most Linux distros by default.) When your application crashes, you may have seen something like:

> Segmentation fault (**core dumped**)

If core dumps are enabled, **a file will be created named `core` that contains information about the program's state when it crashed**, so you can use a tool like `gdb` to debug crashes after they occur

See [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) for more info.